# PHP | Design product control and dynamic assignment

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a dynamic product assignment project.

The goal is to assign 4 regions of a nation to each member:

Ex: I take the regions that make up the nation: Italy.
The number of regions is: 20

regions:

```
Abruzzo
Basilicata
Calabria
Campania
Emilia Romagna
Friuli Venezia Giulia
Lazio
Liguria
Lombardia
Marche
Molise
Piemonte
Provincia Autonoma di Bolzano
Provincia Autonoma di Trento
Puglia
Sardegna
Sicilia
Toscana
Umbria
Valle d'Aosta
Veneto
```

Each time a user signs up, he is assigned a code: ex: `6675`

When the user signs up, the dynamic goal would be: count the users already assigned to the regions and insert this user in the 4 regions that have the fewest users, so that as users sign up, they do not there would be disproportions between regions and assigned numbers of users

But I can't focus well if it would be correct to build a db like this:

```
id_reg |  Abruzzo  | Basilicata   |  Calabria | etc

724         6675         6675         6675
```

or:

```
id_reg    |   reg.   | cod_user

  724       Abbruzzo    6675
  725      Basilicata |  6675

etc...
```

With respect to the objective, it counts how many users have assigned the regions and assigns to the new user the regions that have fewer users assigned, which is the most correct structure?

Comment: It's the latter one, where you have one row for each region assignment.

Comment: @Progman Thanks for your answer, I also thought the same thing, but for further verification I wanted to ask a question

Comment: Even if it wasn't the latter, it definitely wouldn't be the former